# how can I use the function of file_get_contents in php to read the file content in a specific folder?

Tags: php

For example, I have a image file in the /upload folder. How can I use the function of file_get_contents in php to get the  info of the file which is in the /upload folder( a specific directory). What are the parameter that I need to include?

Comment: what do you mean with "info of the file" ?

Comment: The content that the file_get_contents return

Comment: FYI: `file_get_contents` doesn't return any information, just the content of the file (so for an image, do you know what does it means?)

Comment: I just want to use this function for a file in a specified folder.

Comment: I'm not English/American but I write in a decent english (I suppose) so what's wrong with my question? What do you want for files from that folder? Their content or some info (size,creation date, ecc..) ?

Comment: depending on the kind of information that you want, file_get_contents would be the right option or not, that's why it's important to know what do you want to get from the file.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which folder the current file is in.

If you use file_get_contents from a file of a different folder: `file_get_contents(../upload/filename)`.

If you use file_get_contents from a file within the upload folder: `file_get_contents('filename')`

If you use file_get_contents from a file within a subfolder of the upload folder: `file_get_contents('../filename')`

Answer (score 0):

[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) -> Reads entire file into a string

[getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) -> Gets information from the image.

For images you can use the GD library, the exif or the imagemagick libraries, all quite common on almost every PHP installation.